# Problema con Angular build prod

Tags: angularjs-2.0

he creado un proyecto en angular `cli version 1.6.1` y todo está correcto en modo desarrollo. Sin embargo, al compilar con `ng build --prod`, la ruta amigable escrita en el fichero `app.routing.ts`, se descompone en dos parametros get, que corresponden con dos campos de formulario enlazados con two way data binding. No me devuelve ningún error, ni pista alguna que me sirva de guía.

Comment: Hola Francisco, bienvenido a SO. Te recomiendo leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recidiva. También haz el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber mas de como funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla!!

Comment: Ok, gracias ...

Comment: He compilado solo con ng build y lo hace bien, no entiendo que esta pasando

Comment: Son errores que suelen suceder en Angular, pero pon tu `app.routing.ts`, como lo importas, todo lo que nos pueda facilitar la reproducción del error. Como se explica en la sección de Como Preguntar.

Comment: Me auto respondo. He actualizado la versión de angular cli tanto global como de la carpeta del proyecto y ya va bien. Se vé que era un bug de la versión que estaba usando.